# MVC 4 and JsonResult format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jsonresult

have a problem with the result format of this code

```
public JsonResult getCategorias(int? id)
{
  var res = from c in db.Categorias
  where (( id.HasValue && c.CategoriaPadre == id.Value) || (!id.HasValue && c.CategoriaPadre == null))
  select new { id = c.Id, label = c.Descripcion };

  return this.Json(res, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

this return a `json`:

`[{"id":21,"label":"Marketing3"},{"id":22,"label":"Marketing4"}]`

But i need a `json` with this format:

`{"21":"Marketing3","22":"Marketing4"}`

What can i do?

Thanks a lot and sorry my english.

Comment: u want to convert your list into a hash?

Comment: Hi Dave... yes, just that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your return with:

```
var dictionary = res.ToDictionary(v => v.id, v => label);
 return this.Json(dictionary, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you return a `_JsonResult_` it takes the object and automatically formats this way

```
    {
        "Property1":"Value1",
        "Property2"_"Value2",
        ...
    }
```

If you really need other format you could return a `_ViewResult_` from your action, add a View and manually write the json. But for this especific format you could use something similar to the Garath's answer.

Comment: daniel, welcome to stack. I hope you continue answering questions. But ask yourself, did you add value this time?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this:-

```
public static KeyValuePair<string,string> KeyValue(YourClass obj)
        {
            return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(obj.id, obj.label);
        }
```

Before call

```
Json(result.ConvertAll(i => KeyValue(i)), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is possible to do with JsonResult, but you can use [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/) and it's LINQ support (look on the "LINQ to JSON \ Creating Json", so your method will be something like

```
public JsonResult getCategorias(int? id)
{
  var properties = from c in db.Categorias
    where (( id.HasValue && c.CategoriaPadre == id.Value) || (!id.HasValue && c.CategoriaPadre == null))
    select JsonProperty(c.Id.ToString(), c.Descripcion);

  var res = new JObject(properties.ToArray());

  return Content(res.ToString(), "application/json");
}
```