# Convert Json data into C# string

Tags: c#, json

I have JsonResult with Data property and I don't know what's inside that property. I want to get a string containing what's inside JsonResult.Data. There is ToString() method working for Results inheriting from ActionResult so I tried convert using JsonResult.Data.ToString() but I got an exception saying that it can't be converted to string. Is there something I can do about it? I don't need well formated object, I just need to see data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940397/mvc-4-and-jsonresult-format

Answer (score 0):

If you have a JsonResult, you can use the [JavaScriptSerializer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx).

Put the JsonResult into a call to the JavaScriptSerializer's [Serialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to get the string.

You can also look into Json.net for getting an individual property.

Comment: None of this methods worked for me. I've always got the same exception.